# pointing yyin to a FILE* inside of mfcalc example

Tags: c, bison

EDIT: accepted solution below.

I'm working on the Bison mfcalc example here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Mfcalc-Main

I would like to be able to read from a file, rather than stdin. I have their example up and running, but because they've redefined yylex(), getting the parser to read from a file isn't as simple as it usually is.

Anyone that can help would be greatly appreciated!

PS. Something like this: http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/getc.html
But I'm not so good with C. I'll be trying to implement this in the meantime.

So you would need to modify this:

```
int
yylex (void)
{
    int c;

    /* Ignore white space, get first nonwhite character.  */
    while ((c = getchar ()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
    continue;

    if (c == EOF)
    return 0;
    /* Char starts a number => parse the number.         */
    if (c == '.' || isdigit (c))
    {
        ungetc (c, stdin);
        scanf ("%d", &yylval.NUM);
        return NUM;
    }

    /* Char starts an identifier => read the name.       */
    if (isalpha (c))
    {
        /* Initially make the buffer long enough
         for a 40-character symbol name.  */
        static size_t length = 40;
        static char *symbuf = 0;
        symrec *s;
        int i;
        if (!symbuf)
        symbuf = (char *) malloc (length + 1);

        i = 0;
        do
        {
            /* If buffer is full, make it bigger.        */
            if (i == length)
            {
                length *= 2;
                symbuf = (char *) realloc (symbuf, length + 1);
            }
            /* Add this character to the buffer.         */
            symbuf[i++] = c;
            /* Get another character.                    */
            c = getchar ();
        }
        while (isalnum (c));

        ungetc (c, stdin);
        symbuf[i] = '\0';
        s = getsym (symbuf);
        if (s == 0)
        s = putsym (symbuf, VAR);
        *((symrec**) &yylval) = s;
        return s->type;
    }

    /* Any other character is a token by itself.        */
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Nice to see you're using Beej

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with bison.

In C `getchar` reads from `stdin`.  If you want to use a different `FILE *`, use `getc` instead.  So go over the yylex code you have above and replace `getchar()` with `getc(yyin)` (or whatever the name of your `FILE *` is), as well as replacing all the other references to `stdin` with `yyin`.  Similarly, `scanf` reads from `stdin` and `fscanf` reads from a different `FILE *`

Comment: Actually, it has everything to do with Bison, and if you'd read the comments, you'd know I already did that and what the result was. Please read this stuff before you post. I mean, I wouldn't be posting on here for advice on the differences between getchar() and getc(). I can get that from google.

Comment: Well, you never show what you try, but taking the mfcalc example and replacing `getchar` with `getc` and `scanf` with `fscanf` works perfectly for me.  Nothing particularly special or connected with bison.

Comment: I forgot to change scanf! arghhhhh

Comment: I missed scanf too on the first readthrough, but it was obvious when trying to run the program (which hung in scanf).

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin, if you read the Bison texinfo documentation, you'll see that Bison **never deals directly with the input**.  It delegates input to an `yylex()` routine that you have to provide.  If you have used `flex(1)` for the input, then you'll have to touch there (in the flex specification file), but if you have written actually the scanner yourself, then it's your problem inside `yylex()` and (again) nothing related with Bison.

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin, trying to dig in the samples is good, but sometimes is far better to dig in the documentation, and Bison has plenty of it.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code I see now, how about changing the getchar() to read from a specified FILE*, i.e. fgetc.   Then set the FILE* (a global unfortunately) to either stdout or the result of an fopen() call.

Obviously change the ungetc to use that FILE* as well.

```
if (condition){
    globalFilePointer = fopen("something.txt","r");
} else {
    globalFilePointer = stdin;
}
```

Comment: Yes, normally I'd have:
    FILE *myfile = fopen(...);
    yyin = myfile

But that doesn't work here. Check the mfcalc example out.

Comment: Okay, here's a basic problem.  I see now that your routine uses getchar, i.e. stdin.  Perhaps the answer is as simple as changing stdin via freopen(). I'll modify the answer code above.

Comment: You and I both made the same mistake about yyin, actually.  The yyin business comes from lex or flex.  This custom yylex() is not related to that.  I usually use flex when using bison, so yyin seemed completely normal when I first responded.

Comment: By the way, I did something like this ages ago and what came to bite me was dependence on FILE* which made reading from a string very difficult.  If you are just doing a short-lived project where FILE suffices, don't worry about this comment.  Good luck.  Bison is fun once you get the hang of it.

Comment: I was already enroute to doing what you posted, before you posted. Ill get back at it in a minute, but had hoped someone already had some boilerplate code.

Comment: So it compiles with the edits from the link I posted in my question, but doesn't appear to be reading anything from the file.

Comment: "The edits from the link" is totally meaningless. What edits, exactly?

Comment: Changing getchar to getc, for example. The BEEJ link. Yes it only makes sense if you understand the context, but that is necessary for someone to solve anyway, is it not ?

Comment: @dylan: i understand the context just fine but there are no indicated edits that I can see. If you change the all the input functions to introduce yyin in place of stdin, implicit or explicit, then things should work as expected: howevef, you said that they don't. Thus, I conclude that the edits you made are essentially unknowable to anyone not looking over your shoulder, for which reason I assert that your description of the edits is not adequate...

Comment: IOW, your statement was essentially equivalent to saying "I did something which I thought would fix the problem but it didn't. What did I do wrong?" To which the only possible response is "I haven't the faintest idea. What did you do?" I mention all this in case you are tempted to continue using SO; getting good answers is much more likely if you ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

The question has nothing to do with Bison.  Bison is a parser generator that is commonly used with `flex(1)` to provide the input routine it uses to get the tokens.  For input delegation, it uses a routine, commonly named `yylex()` that provides **the next token**, and this routine, when provided by you, has to deal with the actual input (you are free to select if you read input with `getchar(3)`, `fgetc(3)` or simply from `read(2)`).

If you are providing `yylex()` from a scanner description processed by `flex(2)`, you'll have to read the texinfo documentation of `flex(1)` to know how to properly switch input to another file, as `flex(1)` doesn't use `getchar(3)` for that purpose, and buffers internally as much input as neccesary to allow for unbounded pushback.  Actually, it's a problem (and *flex provides several macros to assist you in switching buffers*) to change input in the middle of scanning (for example, to solve the `include file` problem), as flex can be (or not) one token ahead in the input, when you decide to switch buffers, and some state must be pushed back.